# What does 'pwd' mean? In context of this install script

Tags: command-line, package-management, scripts, encryption, security

I have an install command for a particular package contained within a folder

It's a package for encryption and security

Could someone explain for me exactly what `'pwd'` might mean?

```
./install_***.sh `pwd`
```

I am guessing shorthand for password?

Please advise...

Answer (score 8):

`pwd` is a simple command that outputs your Present Working Directory (apparently the command stands for Print Working Directory), or whatever folder you've `cd`ed into. This is used in backticks, which instructs bash to execute `pwd` and then pass it as an argument to `./install_***.sh`. All it's doing is simply telling the installation script where you are on your hard drive. If you were in the folder, for example, `/home/billy/Documents` when you executed the script, this would be the exact same as executing

`./install_***.sh /home/billy/Documents`

It's not a placeholder put in by the documentation or anything, it's an actual command.

### Update

As mentions in comments by @ThomasWard, backticks [are, at least sort of, deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated), and you should use `"$(pwd)"` instead

Comment: Completely accurate, but whatever package or guide you're using is using older (and discouraged) approaches to getting output.  `./install_***.sh "$(pwd)"` is probably a safer bet, but otherwise your answer is accurate :)

Comment: The acronym stands for "Print Working Directory". Source: man pwd

Comment: @ThomasWard Could you please explain why this is discouraged? Why would '$' be a safer bet?

Comment: @ThomasWard Backticks are [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) compliant and can be double-quoted.